# How Can I have abstract parameters in method?

Tags: c#, oop

Basiclly I have a class like `Individual` and another class that inherits from it - `IndividualForSomeAnotherWork`.

I have a class called `Population` too and methods like `Add(Individual individual)`.

Can I pass the `IndividualForSomeAnotherWork` to Add method through `Individual` type? Or should I use interface or abstract class? I'm asking because I'm getting `NullReferenceException` all the time.

EDIT: 
Sorry for not answering so long. My problem was not initializing a List containing objects so I couldn't add to it. But I also wanted to know that can I pass arguments as I said earlier. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Some sample code would be nice to assist us in fully understanding the issue.

Comment: individual is null. Check how it creates.

Comment: You: _Can I pass the `IndividualForSomeAnotherWork` to `Add` method through `Individual` type?_ Sure. When the former inherits from the latter, that is exactly what you can. An `IndividualForSomeAnotherWork` ***is*** an `Individual`. The exception you mention must be something else. We need to see your code. Do you "downcast" with the `as` keyword?

Comment: If you try to write a minimal program that reproduces your error, I think you'll find that it works.  The NullReferenceException is not directly related to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend an `IIndividual` type of interface. In this case, if you have:

```
abstract class Individual : IIndividual {

}

class IndividualForSomeOtherWork : Individual {

}
```

... then `Population.Add(IIndividual Individual)` will accept the base class `Individual` as well as any descendants of `Individual`.

Think of the interface as a contract with the Population class that any individual within it's collection will have implemented all the functions it requires of the individual.

Note that the abstract `Individual` is not required to implement all functions defined within the interface. If the interface requires:

```
interface IIndividual {
   void DoWork();
}
```

... then the base `Individual` is not knowledgeable of what specialized work an `IndividualForSomeOtherWork` will actually perform. So in the abstract class:

```
abstract void DoWork();
```

This function must be defined within the specialized individual descendants.

Comment: Why is it better, by your recommendation, to have an extra type, the interface, "over" the abstract base class. Why not just use the two classes? Do you know something we don't about his scenario?

Comment: Not that I know anything more or less about *his* scenario. I know and understand object-oriented programming. Aside from that, the interface allows for unit-testing and response injection and is generally considered good practice to use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass an `IndividualForSomeAnotherWork` to `Add(Individual individual)`. It should work correctly. Your error is due to something else. Try debugging it yourself, or post more details and code and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what you are trying to do here, an abstract class is not fundamentally different from an interface.  In both cases it's not possible to have a argument whose type exactly matches the type of the formal parameter.  See [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx) for an explicit example of this (Image is an abstract class).

The NullReferenceException you are seeing is not directly related to the parameter type being abstract.